# I'm getting webpack error when building my next.js project on my ubuntu server

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu-16.04, next.js, styled-components

I've got a nextjs project that work well in ly local laptop which runs `windows 10`,but when i clone the same projet from my bitbucket repository and build i get webpack problems.

Here is my **.babelrc** config:

```
{
    "presets": [
      "next/babel"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "styled-components",
        {
          "ssr": true,
          "displayName": true,
          "preprocess": false
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "rdc-infrastructure-next",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@trendmicro/react-sidenav": "^0.4.5",
    "@urbica/react-map-gl": "^1.8.0",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chroma-js": "^2.0.4",
    "deck.gl": "^7.1.11",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.2.0",
    "next": "^8.1.0",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.0",
    "next-fonts": "^0.17.0",
    "next-images": "^1.1.2",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^3.0.0-alpha.3",
    "nouislider-react": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "react-bootstrap-sidebar": "^0.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-horizontal-timeline": "^1.5.3",
    "react-map-gl": "^5.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-with-styles": "^3.2.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rheostat": "^3.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.1",
    "styled-components-breakpoint": "^2.1.1",
    "styled-components-modifiers": "^1.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.6",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Every is fine and i don't see any problem in any of my configurations.But here is the error that i get when i run **yarn dev** .Yarn is already installed in my linux ubuntu server **Ubuntu 16.04.6 (LTS) x64** because i'm already using it for managing packages for the **API** on the same server.
Here is the error that i'm getting when i run **yarn dev** :

```
yarn run v1.17.3
$ next
[ wait ]  starting the development server ...
[ info ]  waiting on http://localhost:3000 ...
[ error ] ./pages/_app.js
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-styled-components' from '/home/jochri3/projet-infrastructures/infrastructure-map'
- If you want to resolve "styled-components", use "module:styled-components"
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
[ wait ]  compiling ...
[ error ] ./pages/_app.js
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-styled-components' from '/home/jochri3/projet-infrastructures/infrastructure-map'
- If you want to resolve "styled-components", use "module:styled-components"
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I already did `yarn install` after i cloned the repository

How can i solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Just to confirm, you did `yarn install` after cloning right?

Comment: Yes i did `yarn install`